# Access violation in scanf_s

Tags: c, visual-studio, runtime-error

I'm trying to make a program to just see what I can do with structures in C.  But getting an error in the main function at `scanf_s("%s", &user.name)`:

> Exception thrown at 0x5C26D3EC (ucrtbased.dll) in StructureTest.exe:
>
> 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01341000. occurred

I also get some [compiler warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARsRB.png).  This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct birthdate {
    int day;
    char month[9];
    int year;
};

typedef struct birthdate dob;
    struct info {
    char name[40];
    dob birthdate;
    int age;
    char sex[6];
    char *origin; 
};
void printinfo(struct info user) {
    printf("---- User Data ----\n");
    printf("Name: %s\n", user.name);
    printf("Date of birth: %d/%s/%d\n", user.birthdate.day, 
    user.birthdate.month, user.birthdate.year);
    printf("Age: %d\n", user.age);
    printf("Sex: %s\n", user.sex);
    printf("Country of origin: %s", user.origin);
}

int main() {
    printf("--Please enter your info--\n");
    struct info user;   
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &user.name); // <-- exception thrown here
    printf("Please enter your date of birth in the format (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
    scanf_s("%d %s %d", &user.birthdate.day, &user.birthdate.month,
    &user.birthdate.year);
    printf("Please enter your age: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &user.age);
    printf("Please enter your gender ([M]ale/[F]emale): ");
    scanf_s("%s", &user.sex);
    printf("Please enter your country of origin: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &user.origin); // <- Another exception thrown here

    printf("\n\n");
    printinfo(user);

    printf("\nPress ENTER to continue..");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not really experienced with structures yet, but I suspect it might have something to do with arrays and pointers, and the name I write in going into nowhere.

Comment: What is the output? Where is the error occuring?

Comment: Enable all warnings and review proper usage if `scanf_s("%s", &user.name);`  What compiler are you using?  What warnings did you receive when compiling?

Comment: `scanf_s` is a Microsoft Visual C extension.   It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017).

Answer (score 3):

You didn't show the input you feed to the program.

There are some minor mistakes and some major in your program:

- First, you have been too tigth in the allocation of `char` arrays.  For example, `month` field in `birthdate` struct has only 9 spaces to store the month, and this means you cannot store a month like `september` that requires 9 characters *plus one more for the `\0` nul character at the end of the string*.  This can be the problem with your execution if you aren't careful.
- It's not common practice to pass `struct`s directly *by value* to a function, as this makes the compiler to copy the complete struct contents into the parameter stack.  It's more common to pass the struct by reference, as in

  ```
    void printinfo(struct info *user);
  ```

  and then calling it as

  ```
    printinfo(&user);
  ```

  which makes the compiler to pass only a pointer to the structure, saving time and memory.

I have not found the `scanf_s` function in my manual online, where did you get it?  Well, after some digging, I found them... from the VC manual for those functions (not standard, just a Microsoft extension):

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s **require** the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed **as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable**...

so you must use

```
scanf_s("%s", &user.name, sizeof user.name - 1);
```

and the same for the other strings you are reading.

## NOTE

Those `_s` suffixed functions are only **Microsoft extensions to their compiler**.  They are not portable (nor standard in anyway) and don't appear in the majority of C implementations.   It's better not to use them, except if you are going to use only Microsoft C compilers  (and you are not warranted for them to disappear in the future).  There are other means to check for buffer size than to use nonstandard functions, e.g.

```
scanf("%.39s", user.name); /* there's no need to use the & operator here */
```

(in case you need to pass the size as a parameter, you can do the following):

```
SCANF("%.*s", sizeof user.name - 1, user.name);
```

will do the work, or

```
fgets(user.name, sizeof user.name, stdin);
```

(this call requires you to eliminate the last `\n` from the string) both of these calls are standard, included in `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: Good answer! Is there a way to tell MS VC to detect the argument mismatch for `scanf_s` and issue a warning or better an error ?

Comment: nope.... there's no way to see how (or if there are more parameters) a parameter is encoded, or the size of parameters from the inside of a variadic function that can be called different ways from different parts of your program.  Compilers try to tight enough the parameters and don't delimit them so you can check if there are more parameters awaiting to be processed, so the problem is that `scanf_s` is just considering that there's one more parameter and it's using what exists in the register/stack position and reinterpreting it as a `size_t` data.

Comment: the information about parameter types, number of, or sizes, is lost in the compilation process... the program runs in the assumption that everything has been well prepared.  No meta information about parameters remains to be available at run time.

Comment: I am well aware of the limitations of the `var_arg` parameter passing system, but modern compilers can be instructed to verify the consistency between the format string and the actual arguments passed at compile time, if the format string is a literal of course. `gcc -Wall` and `clang -Weverything` do that, and it is a life saver, I was wondering if MSVC had a similar capability.

Comment: @chqrlie, moderns compilers.... again.... are you discussing about some specific implementation?  Is MSVC aware of this? I suggested not to use Microsoft specific implementations (or non-standard routines)  I know all you say, but if we concentrate on the environment we have, you'll get that MSVC doesn't check argument lists.

Comment: The `scanf_s()` function is actually standardized in the optional [Annex K of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.4).  However, [Annex K is likely not long for this world, and Microsoft's implementation received this from the C standards committee](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1967.htm):  "As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Comment: @LuisColorado: OK, no harm intended, I agree with your advice not to use these extensions and use `scanf("%.39s", user.name);` instead. Too bad MSVC does not check argument lists.

Comment: @chqrlie, in case you need to pass the value as a parameter (not the string representation) you can use `"%.*s", sizeof user.name - 1, user.name` instead.  So no need to implement `scanf_s` anyway.

Comment: @LuisColorado: your suggestion is interesting, but it is not part of the C language yet. The `*` is interpreted by `scanf()` as an assignment suppression option, the maximum field width must be specified in decimal, it cannot be passed as an extra argument and the decimal point `.` is not supported by `scanf()`, it introduces the precision for the `printf` family of functions only.

Comment: It should be `user.name`, not `&user.name`

Comment: @M.M, it doesn't matter... `printf(3)` requires a `char *` and a `char [N]` promotes to a `char *` on parameter passing to a function.  So, the two received values are the same, either.  You can pass an array of char reference instead of a char pointer, both will be promoted to `char *`.

Comment: @LuisColorado `&user.name` has type `char (*)[N]` which does not implicitly convert to `char *`

Comment: @M.M, You are right, except in the passing of a parameter to a function, in which case all `char []` converts to a `char *`.  BTW, an array of char is type `char [N]` and not `char (*)[N]`.  You can test this, and you can be a C++ lawyer, but in C you don't get even a warning.  Call it a legacy issue, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ahhhh I understand now, thanks so much! My teacher recommended using Codeblocks but I prefer Visual studio, and I knew there were some differences but I never really took care to read up on them. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problems using `scanf_s` mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53058517/6782754) you also provide a wrong parameter:

```
scanf_s("%s", &user.origin);
```

With `origin` being a pointer to `char`, that's not the correct type. You need to provide a `char *` but you provide a `char **`.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, what's the difference?

Comment: A `char *` points to a single character or an array of characters. This could be used to store a string. A `char **` points to a pointer. You cannot store a string in the space occupied by a pointer. And you do not allocate any memory anyway.